# Java error: variable playerClass might not have been initialized

Tags: java

I have looked everywhere and all solutions to this problem are more complicated situations. I have been programming a few years but am pretty new to Java.

When I started the program, it said "error: variable playerClass might not have been initialized". If you know how to help, it would be greatly appreciated to let me know!"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // reg variables
    int health;
    int damage;
    int defense;
    int powerUp;
    int currentLevel;
    int difficulty;
    int playerClass;

    // level types
    boolean intro;
    boolean reglevel = false;
    boolean bossFight = false;
    boolean puzzle = false;

    // scanner
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    // game start
    intro = true;

    if (intro = true) {
      System.out.println("Select a class:");
      System.out.println("[Press number relating to class]");
      System.out.println("-1 - Fighter [25 Health, 10 Damage, 5 Defense");
      System.out.println("-2 - Archer [15 Health, 10 Damage, 1 Defense, Passive: Ranged");
      System.out.println("-3 - Mage [20 Health, 15 Damage, 3 Defense, Ability: Fireball");
      playerClass = userInput.nextInt();
    }

    if (playerClass == 1) {
      System.out.println("You have selected Fighter! You use your sword to fight enemies.");
      System.out.println("What difficulty do you want your dungeon to be?");
      System.out.println("Type number related to difficulty:");
      System.out.println("1: Easy");
      System.out.println("2: Medium");
      System.out.println("3: Hard");
      difficulty = userInput.nextInt();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens if `intro` is `false`? `playerClass` will not be initialized. You say / claim it won't happen but the compiler cannot know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to initialize the variable. For example by writing :
int playerClass = 0.

The compiler should not bother you after this

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved the issue. I guess I just thought that if playerClass wasn't equal to anything, it would just skip the entire if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise `playerClass` first; as @luk2302 cleared, your variable is conditionally initialised, and hence compiler won't be sure of that.